# where clause in wpf

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new in WPF,in my viewmodel, I have defined one list 
& I want to return sublist (i.e. 30 in my case) based on some condition.
I have used below way.

```
private readonly IEnumerable<int> _numbers;
 _numbers= new List<int>() {30,60};

1. 
public Number
{
 get
{
   return (mynum== 30) ? _numbers.Where(x => x == 30)
                       .ToList()
                    : _numbers;
  }
}

OR
2. 
public Number
{
 get
{
   return (mynum== 30) ? new list<int>() {30}   : _numbers;
  }
}
```

which one is correct/right way to do this?
does where clause always create new list or return extracted list?

Thanks,

Comment: what is the return type of `Number` property?

Comment: In either case I would not return the underlying `_numbers` member but always a copy - otherwise a unscrupulous client could directly change the contents of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions.

`Where` clause doesn't return a new list. It returns an `Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>` by applying predicate (condition) to the each element of the source. So you can change original items from source list as references are pointing to the same objects.

On the other hand applying `.ToList()` creates a copy so you can't *harm* original collection:

```
var copy = source.ToList();
```

which is the same as

```
var copy = new List<TSource>(source);
```

---

So analyzing code you have posted we have functionally same snippets for both. After generalizing it a bit so it will look same:

```
public Number
{
   get
   {
      var copy = _numbers.Where(x => x == 30).ToList();
      // which is the same as
      var filteredList = _numbers.Where(x => x == 30);
      copy = new List<int>(filteredList);
      return (mynum == 30) ? copy : _numbers;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two examples are not exactly the same, because the first would potentially return multiple instances of "30" (assuming `_numbers` isn't actually hardcoded to just 30 and 60), whereas the second would always only return a single `30` result.

Personally, I think the first option makes more sense in most situations, but without having an understanding of your needs, no one can really say for sure.